# Syntax for using OpenCover with a service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, nunit, opencover

I am trying to incorporate code coverage into an application. Since I am using VS Express, OpenCover seemed like the best (read: only) option.
The application is a silverlight web application, with multiple services. I have managed to get the silverlight code coverage to work with the sample commandline that was provided in the usage document. However, when I try the sample commandline for the service layer, it doesn't work. It gives

```
Service 'Application\Sample.Web.WCF\SampleService.svc' cannot be found - have you sp
ecified your arguments correctly?
```

This is the input that I pass:

```
OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"Application\Sample.Web.WCF\SampleService.svc" -service –register
```

I needed help on what kind of arguments is missing. Also in the service section of the usage manual, it mentions to input "Local Service" instead of "Local System". Where do I input that?

And how do I point to the .pdb files?

I saw a similar article called "How do I hook into a service with OpenCover?" but I do not understand how/what profile to pre-register using regsvr32 and also do I give the particular service or just the folder path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the syntax for running against a windows service when what you have is an app that looks runs under IIS (or [iisexpress](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview))

The service layer (.svc) that you have is not a windows service but a wcf-web service; use the same (similar) syntax as you did to launch your silverlight application.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, Yes, my application runs against IIS, so I tried the following : OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user "-target:C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "-targetargs:http://localhost/SampleServices/SampleService.svc" "-targetdir:Application\Sample.Web.WCF\Bin" -output:opencoverSvcResult.xml

This doesn't work. It gives the following error: 
No results - no assemblies that matched the supplied filter were instrumented this could be due to missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf)

Comment: The web service runs in IIS not in internet explorer (that just views the output returned) - sorry for the misdirection. Use iisexpress to host your site (easier to automate) and then exercise it using your silverlight application. Do you have any automated unit tests (these are the better way to gather code coverage), integration tests are notoriously difficult to setup.

Comment: Thanks again Shaun, almost there... 
Running the following - OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user "-target:NUnit\nunit.exe" "-targetdir:Application\Sample.Web.WCF\bin" -output:opencoverSvcResult.xml gives me an output, on running the NUnit test cases, but on checking the report, it mentions 0% coverage for Service files that got run on the NUnit app.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Really appreciate the patience.

Comment: What are your `targetargs`?

Comment: I took the latest version of OpenCover and realized what you meant by running it against IIS. Using the syntax given in that doc, it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.